# exporting to pdf from an access report with a name from the data

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf

I am wanting to export from an Access report to a pdf who name is governed by the data within the report.

I have created the code below but it is only saving the file as `_.pdf` and not the values I want.

I have the report open when ruinning this. It looks as though the data from the report isnt coming through to the code but I'm not sure how and if this is correct.

Could someone help me in as plain english as possible.
Many thanks

```
Sub outputpdf()

    Dim myPath As String
    Dim strReportName As String
    Dim stritem As String
    Dim strcont As String
    Dim strid As String
    Dim struniq As String

    DoCmd.OpenReport "outputreport", acViewPreview

    myPath = "D:\simon\test\"

    strReportName = stritem + strcont + ".pdf"
    'strReportName = Item + contract_number + "_"+ ".pdf"

    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, myPath & strReportName, False

    DoCmd.Close acReport, "outputreport"

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Chris i am now getting a 2501 error and the outputto action is being cancelled. should i be linking the strings to the data in some way?

Comment: Where are stritem and strcont populated?

Answer (score 1):

Access and VBA concatenation use the `&` operator and not `+` like C languages.

```
strReportName = stritem + strcont + ".pdf"
```

To

```
strReportName = strItem & strcont & ".pdf"
```

You have it right in the bottom part, I think...

Edit:

build it

```
Sub ObjectBuilder()
Dim item As String, cont As String

item = InputBox("Enter Item", "Item", "12345")
cont = InputBox("Enter Container?", "Container", "Shipping Crate")

OutputPdf item, cont

End Sub
```

Then use it

```
Sub OutputPdf(item As String, cont As String)
'your code
 strItem = item
 strCont = cont
End Sub
```

Comment: HI BMO I changed this and although it is not returning an error it is still saving the file as _.pdf. I think its not seeing the values of the data.Have you any idea on how to get it to see them? cheers Simon

Comment: set a breakpoint on `DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, myPath & strReportName, False'` and over over the `strReportName` variable. As I re-read your code, how are `stritem` and `strcont` being populated? There is no assignment, which would explain why it's blank.

Comment: Both stritem and strcont are "". How do I assign values to them?

Comment: It depends on what they represent. if `ouputpdf()` is being called from some other function, you may need to 'pass in' the value using arguments. See edited answer.

Comment: outputpdf() is srand alone except i will run it from a macro in access. Will that work?

Comment: Then instead of passing the argument in, `ouputpdf` will have to get the values, but if the item is being created elsewhere it's probably a best practice to give the information to `outputpdf` instead of making it get it itself.

Comment: Soryy for seeming thick but how do I do this?

Comment: You would need to post more code. Some from the function that is calling `outputpdf`

Comment: Sorry but im lost on this. The data appears in the report and is a single set of records from a table. Because the report has been opened would the values not be available for the code?

Comment: Well something has to kick this event off, what does that? We can start there.

Comment: ok, The report which is set to show one particular line of data opens, This then needs to be exported as a pdf with the name of the file including certain fields that appear in the report.

Comment: `+` character is allowed in VBA for concatenation but `&` is preferred although there are situations where `+` is useful.